# Proof writing for polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let the polynomial  $f(x)=x^n+a_1 x^{n-1}+a_2 x^{n-2}+.....a_{n-1}x+a_n$ have integral coefficients. If there exists four distinct integers $a,b,c$ and $d$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=f(d)=5$ show that there is no integer $k$ such that $f(k)=8$

I have tried to prove it but I somehow feel that my proof is incorrect please point out the errors and suggest some other way to do the question.
This how I proceeded 
$\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}=x^n+a_1 x^{n-1}+a_2 x^{n-2}+.....a_{n-1}x+a_n $

$\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}=5$
 hence $\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{5}=a-1$ 
Since $a$ is an integer $a-1$ will also be an integer hence $5|a^{n+1}-1$

Using fermat's little theorem we know that $a^4-1\equiv_5 0$ 
Since $f(a)=5$ we get $n+1=4$

Let k be an integer such that $f(k)=8$
$\frac{a^4-1}{8}=a-1$ Since  $a-1$ is an integer $8|a^4-1$

We will consider two cases

1. when $a$ is an even integer
2. when $ a$ is an odd integer

If $a$ is even then $a^4-1$ will be odd and it not be divisible by $8$

If $a$ is odd then it will be relatively  prime to $8$ hence $8$ will be Carmichael number

$a^7-1\equiv0(mod8)$  which proves that $a^4-1$ is not divisible by 8.
$\therefore$ there  is no integer k such that $f(k)=8$

Comment: $\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}=x^n+a_1 x^{n-1}+a_2 x^{n-2}+.....a_{n-1}x+a_n$?????

Comment: As Kenny Lau said in the comment above, the mistake in your proof is right at the beginning.

Comment: Then how should I go about with the question?

Comment: Please can you people post the right  proof as the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: show that if $f(a) = f(b) = f(c) = f(d) = 5$, then

$$f(x) = 5 + (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) g(x)$$

for some polynomial $g$ with integer coefficients. If $f(e) = 8$, then

$$(e-a)(e-b)(e-c)(e-d) g(e) = 3,$$

but a product of four distinct integers can't be a divisor of $3$.

Comment: This is exactly what I would have done, +1. However, a question for @Pulsar. Do you know how to prove that $g$ is in $\mathbb Z[x]$? This is essential for this proof to work.

Comment: @Ennar I could not prove that can you please help?

Comment: @Pulsar, it is too long for a comment. The sketch would be something like this: let $f, g\in \mathbb Z[x]$ such that $g$ is [primitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_part_and_content) and $q\in\mathbb Q[x]$ such that $f = qg$. Then $q\in\mathbb Z[x]$. The proof relies on [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial)), specifically that product of two primitive polynomials is primitive. Another way is to directly apply the fact that both $\mathbb Z[x]$ and $\mathbb Q[x]$ are unique factorization domains.

Comment: @Ennar thanks a lot those articles are very useful

Comment: @Ennar Are you sure this is necessary? I thought it was a lot easier: if $R$ is any ring, we can divide by [monic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial) staying within $R[X]$. If $R$ is also an integral domain, the process of pulling out the factors $x-x_i$ can be continued, so we get the factorization from the answer.

Comment: Adayah, ok, you are right, we can do that. Not only for monic polynomials, but leading coefficient can be any unit. I just immediately skipped to $\mathbb Q[x]$ being Euclidean domain, while the proof of $\mathbb F[x]$ being Euclidean, where $\mathbb F$ is a field, uses this lemma.

Comment: @Ennar Sorry, which lemma does this fact use? I thought the proof that $\deg : \mathbb{F}[x] \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{N}$ is an Euclidean function is a straightforward induction. :p

Comment: Well the lemma you just mentioned, if $f,g\in R[x]$ and $g$'s leading coefficient is unit in $R$, then there exists $q, r\in R[x]$ such that $f = qg + r$. You can incorporate this directly for $R$ field and do what you say.

Answer (score 3):

I think the first part of your solution is wrong ($\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}=x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1$, not $x_n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-1}x+a_n$).

Since $f$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, we have $a-b|f(a)-f(b)$ for all $a, b\in \mathbb{Z}, a\neq b$. Thus if we suppose there exists integer $k$ with $f(k)=8$, we have $k-x|f(k)-f(x)=3$, where $x=a,b,c,d$. Since $a,b,c,d$ are all distinct we have $\{a,b,c,d\}=\{k-3,k-1,k+1,k+3\}$.

Then, consider $g(x)=f(x-k)-5$. $g$ clearly is a monic polynomial with integer coefficients such that $g(0)=3, g(-3)=g(-1)=g(1)=g(3)=0$. If we set $g(x)=x^n+b_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_{n-1}x+b_n$, by conditions we have $b_n=3$ and following:

$3^n+3^{n-1}b_1+\cdots+3b_{n-1}+3=0 \rightarrow 3^{n-1}+3^{n-2}b_1+\cdots+b_{n-1}+1=0$

$(-3)^n+(-3)^{n-1}b_1+\cdots+(-3)b_{n-1}+3=0 \rightarrow (-3)^{n-1}+(-3)^{n-2}b_1+\cdots+b_{n-1}-1=0$

From the first equation we have $b_{n-1}\equiv-1 \mod 3$, while from the second equation we have $b_{n-1}\equiv 1 \mod 3$, a contradiction. Thus there exists no such $f$.

Comment: Why is $b_n=3$ ?please can elaborate a little more on the second half portion of your answer

Comment: @Pulsar Because $b_n = g(0) = 3.$ Also, it should be $g(x) = f(x+k) - 5$ instead of $g(x) = f(x-k) - 5$.

Comment: @Adayah Thanks now I understood  the answer

Comment: @Adayah I made a mistake there :( Thanks!